# Self-reference to User domain does not allow the user to login using spring security in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, grails, spring-security

I have a User domain, which requires a self-reference to some other user like the parent-child relationship.

```
class User{
    String username, password
    boolean enabled, accountExpired, accountLocked, passwordExpired
    static mapWith = "mongo"
    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        password blank: false
    }
    static belongsTo = [parentUser:User]
    static hasMany = [childUser:User]
}
```

This is how I create the parent user, and is able to login.

```
User parentUser = new User(username:paramList.username, password:paramList.password, enabled:true).save(flush:true);
```

This is how I create the child user, but this user is not able to login.

```
User childUser = new User(username:paramList.username, password:paramList.password, enabled:true, parentUser:parentUser).save(flush:true);
```

Stacktrace while logging-in child user.

```
2014-04-29 14:06:30,978 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG util.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Request '/j_spring_security_check' matched by universal pattern '/**'
2014-04-29 14:06:30,978 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /j_spring_security_check at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:30,978 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2014-04-29 14:06:30,978 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@3586d2aa. A new one will be created.
2014-04-29 14:06:30,978 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /j_spring_security_check at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:30,978 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /j_spring_security_check at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:30,979 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG authentication.ProviderManager  - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2014-04-29 14:06:31,766 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices  - Interactive login attempt was unsuccessful.
2014-04-29 14:06:31,767 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices  - Cancelling cookie
2014-04-29 14:06:31,767 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG web.DefaultRedirectStrategy  - Redirecting to '/login/authfail?login_error=1'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,767 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2014-04-29 14:06:31,767 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2014-04-29 14:06:31,784 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG util.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Request '/login/authfail' matched by universal pattern '/**'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,784 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,784 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2014-04-29 14:06:31,784 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@3586d2aa. A new one will be created.
2014-04-29 14:06:31,784 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,784 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,784 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,784 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 5 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,784 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,784 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 7 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,784 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 8 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,787 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /login/authfail?login_error=1; Attributes: [permitAll]
2014-04-29 14:06:31,788 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Previously Authenticated: grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken@f23a7304: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dc730200: Username: __grails.anonymous.user__; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffed504: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: E1A2091E27738124B8C0C27AE339EBB6; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2014-04-29 14:06:31,788 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl  - getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] one can reach [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] in zero or more steps.
2014-04-29 14:06:31,788 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Authorization successful
2014-04-29 14:06:31,788 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2014-04-29 14:06:31,788 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/authfail?login_error=1 at position 9 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SwitchUserFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,789 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/authfail?login_error=1 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2014-04-29 14:06:31,793 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Chain processed normally
2014-04-29 14:06:31,795 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2014-04-29 14:06:31,796 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2014-04-29 14:06:31,806 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG util.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Request '/login/auth' matched by universal pattern '/**'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,806 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/auth?login_error=1&format= at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,807 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2014-04-29 14:06:31,807 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@3586d2aa. A new one will be created.
2014-04-29 14:06:31,807 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/auth?login_error=1&format= at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,808 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/auth?login_error=1&format= at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,808 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/auth?login_error=1&format= at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,808 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/auth?login_error=1&format= at position 5 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,809 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/auth?login_error=1&format= at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,809 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/auth?login_error=1&format= at position 7 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,809 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/auth?login_error=1&format= at position 8 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,810 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /login/auth?login_error=1&format=; Attributes: [permitAll]
2014-04-29 14:06:31,811 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Previously Authenticated: grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken@f23a7304: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dc730200: Username: __grails.anonymous.user__; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffed504: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: E1A2091E27738124B8C0C27AE339EBB6; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2014-04-29 14:06:31,811 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl  - getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] one can reach [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] in zero or more steps.
2014-04-29 14:06:31,811 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Authorization successful
2014-04-29 14:06:31,812 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2014-04-29 14:06:31,812 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/auth?login_error=1&format= at position 9 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SwitchUserFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:31,812 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /login/auth?login_error=1&format= reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2014-04-29 14:06:32,002 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2014-04-29 14:06:32,003 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Chain processed normally
2014-04-29 14:06:32,003 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] DEBUG context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2014-04-29 14:06:32,032 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG util.AntPathRequestMatcher  - Request '/user/current.json' matched by universal pattern '/**'
2014-04-29 14:06:32,032 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /user/current.json at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:32,032 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
2014-04-29 14:06:32,032 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@3586d2aa. A new one will be created.
2014-04-29 14:06:32,032 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /user/current.json at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'MutableLogoutFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:32,032 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /user/current.json at position 3 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:32,032 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /user/current.json at position 4 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:32,032 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /user/current.json at position 5 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:32,032 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /user/current.json at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:32,032 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /user/current.json at position 7 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:32,032 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /user/current.json at position 8 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2014-04-29 14:06:32,034 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /user/current.json; Attributes: [permitAll]
2014-04-29 14:06:32,034 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Previously Authenticated: grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationToken@f23a7304: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@dc730200: Username: __grails.anonymous.user__; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: false; AccountNonExpired: false; credentialsNonExpired: false; AccountNonLocked: false; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffed504: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: E1A2091E27738124B8C0C27AE339EBB6; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2014-04-29 14:06:32,034 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl  - getReachableGrantedAuthorities() - From the roles [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] one can reach [ROLE_ANONYMOUS] in zero or more steps.
2014-04-29 14:06:32,034 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - Authorization successful
2014-04-29 14:06:32,035 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor  - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2014-04-29 14:06:32,035 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /user/current.json at position 9 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SwitchUserFilter'
2014-04-29 14:06:32,035 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy  - /user/current.json reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2014-04-29 14:06:32,036 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG manage.UserController  - params for getUser : [id:current, action:[POST:updateUser, GET:getUser, PUT:enableDisableUser, DELETE:deleteUser], controller:user, format:json]
2014-04-29 14:06:32,055 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository  - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2014-04-29 14:06:32,057 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG access.ExceptionTranslationFilter  - Chain processed normally
2014-04-29 14:06:32,057 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] DEBUG context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter  - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: Do you have any stack-trace of what you are getting when you are logging-in with child user?

Comment: @LalitAgarwal It was not possible to add the stacktrace in comment, so I've edited the question.